# Sass "Error: Can't find stylesheet to import."

Tags: css, sass

I'm running into an issue which seems similar to the one reported in https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/284, but doesn't seem 'fixed' for me. I'm trying to follow the workflow described in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/ to import Bootstrap's SCSS source code.

Here is my (simplified) directory structure:

```
.
├── index.html
├── node_modules
│   ├── @mdi
│   └── bootstrap
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── scss
│   └── peek-solutions2.scss
└── stylesheets
    └── peek-solutions.css
```

I've installed Bootstrap using `npm install bootstrap`; my `package.json` contains the following dependencies:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^2.2.43",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

In `peek-solutions2.scss`, I've added the following line:

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I've tried the `sass --watch` command specifying input and output files in different directories (cf. https://sass-lang.com/guide), but I run into an import error:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:peek-solutions2 kurtpeek$ sass --watch scss/peek-solutions2.scss:stylesheets/peek-solutions2.css
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
@import "functions";
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss 8:9  @import
  scss/peek-solutions2.scss 1:9                      root stylesheet

Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
```

It seems like this is a path issue; `_functions.scss` is in the same directory as `bootstrap.scss` in `node_modules/bootstrap/scss`, but it seems like the `sass` command is expecting it to be in my custom `scss` directory. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally worked around this problem by using Grunt instead of sass to compile and watch the SCSS files. After running `npm install grunt --save-dev`, `npm install grunt-contrib-sass --save-dev`, and `npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev`, I added the following `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    sass: {                              // Task
      dist: {                            // Target
        files: {                         // Dictionary of files
          'stylesheets/main.css': 'scss/main.scss',       // 'destination': 'source'
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      scripts: {
        files: ['**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass'],
      },
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass']);

};
```

Now if I run `grunt watch`, whenever I save `scss/main.scss` it gets compiled into `stylesheets/main.css`:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:peek-solutions2 kurtpeek$ grunt watch
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "scss/main.scss" changed.
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task

Done.
Completed in 1.720s at Sun Jul 01 2018 14:41:11 GMT-0700 (PDT) - Waiting...
```

Answer (score 64):

just delete the dots in the beginning , you must write:

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

in your scss file

Comment: Hello, @adaout, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Given that the `node_modules` folder is in the parent directory, wouldn't removing the preceding dots (`../`) instruct the code to look in the non-existent `scss/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap` folder?

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: This can work if you are running sass from the parent folder. Adding some explanation of this would benefit this answer.

Comment: I really didn't expect this to work, but it did! My `@import`s were slightly different: `@import '~bootstrap/scss/card'`;. Removing the `~` worked.

Answer (score 19):

This happened to me because I was running `ng build --prod` within a folder other than the root project folder, and every other css import breaks.

The solution is to cd to the root folder.

Comment: Or `ng serve` elsewhere other than the root (just outside `src`)

Answer (score 18):

I solved this issue by pointing the imports to the files directly, i.e:

```
@import 'style/components/palette';
```

to

```
@import 'style/components/_palette.scss';
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I had this problem when using NX. This answer works. But why does this solve the issue?

Comment: same. works for me.

Comment: work for me too. I think its because it is root directory for app entrypoint

Answer (score 14):

I solved it by using an extra forward slash @import "//abstracts/variable";

Comment: Do You know why it works? I can't find answer for this.

Comment: same, what is this sorcery?

Comment: This isn't actually a solution, all this does is tell your stylesheet to import a remote resource. While webpack no longer throws an error, you likely won't see the stylesheet loaded in the compiled styles.

Comment: I don't get an error, but unfortunately the import didn't happen. Failed to import style files

Answer (score 9):

For those using the `sass` NPM package and have their own NodeJS build script, make sure that you provide `loadPaths` as an options parameter in your `compile` or `compileAsync` method. For example:

```js
import sass from 'sass';
// const sass = require('sass');

const build = async () => {
    await sass.compileAsync('./src/index.scss',
        {
            sourceMap: true,
            style: 'expanded',
            loadPaths: ['./src']
        }
    );
};
```

Here `./src` is where your main scss file resides, relative to your project directory. You might not need this configuration if the index file is in project root, but most people probably don't put their scss files there.

Comment: I was launching the task by NPM script instead of the GRUNT one

Comment: thanks that was useful, I would also point out that it also work in the CLI, which is what I'm using, with the use of `--load-paths` as per docs: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass#load-path and in my case I just added `--load-path=node_modules` and finally external libs imports started working as they should :)

Answer (score 6):

If, for example your index.scss file is in a directory called 'sass' e.g.

```
├── node_modules
├── sass
│   └── index.scss
```

then you should use this file path:

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 5):

I also got this error and I solved it just using the relative path, like this:
`@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';`

Answer (score 5):

I installed the bootstrap old version which didn't add scss folder in bootstrap under my node module, so I uninstalled my bootstrap by the command `npm uninstall bootstrap` and installed it back by `npm i bootstrap`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using rails and trying to get production to work, you may have run the production command to build assets in your dev environment. For instance:

`yarn build:css`

or

`sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules`

Either way, Rails may be preferring the "built" assets over the dev ones. So you may already have fixed the issue with bootstrap and not know it! Remove your build directory:

`rm -rf app/assets/builds`

and your other asset files will be used.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue in Laravel 9. Remove this symbol. ~

// Bootstrap
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

Answer (score 3):

Importing this bootstrap .scss file directly by **using the relative path pointing to the node_modules** content worked in my case. Webpack really could not make it work.

Another solution in my case was simply removing the '~' before the path:

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Answer (score 3):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpsEV.png)

To resolve this problem, I've removed the special character (~) that is present in the mentioned in the path as such (~). The Path that begin with ~ or . or .. will be called as relative path.

Example for relative path

```
~/ed-grid/ed-grid/
./ed-grid
```

> ~  It denotes the Home Directory

So when we use ~ we should use the / Character for the directory separation
or we should mention the absolute path instead of relative path.

Example for an Absolute path

> /home/username/ed-grid/ed-grid

Answer (score 2):

In `peek-solutions2.scss`, remove the previous code and add this:

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

Answer (score 2):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/615#issuecomment-469884572):

> Dart Sass's command-line interface doesn't look for imports in any location that's not explicitly provided as a --load-path on the command line. Node Sass's CLI may behave differently.

Thus to get the a similar behaviour with `node-sass` use `--load-path`.

```
sass --load-path=./ src/scss/styles.scss dist/css/styles.css
```

This command will load the current `dir` and will resolve `./node_modules` or a possible `./src`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";`,
no forward slash after the tilde.

Comment: Sure, this tip works for rollup postcss plugin. But it deprecated for webpack sass-loader.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with updating `sass` version from `1.26.10` to `1.32.13`.

Answer (score 0):

Check where Bootstrap is in `node_modules` and add

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

for it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be routing issues, if you are on rails use this
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons';

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33024267)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused by the fact that my project was opened in a parent folder

```
 root                ⬅️ my vscode had this folder as a root 
    └── project     ⬅️ should have been in this folder instead
        ├── node_modules
        ├── src
        ├── static
        └── ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a symlink to my C:\dev folder when the physical location was actually E:\dev.  Changing directories from C:\dev\project to E:\dev\project and running the mix command fixed this for me

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Aurelia, WebPack and SASS and you did an NPM install of bootstrap the import will be:

@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and adding this code

```
resolve: {
    alias: [
        {
            // this is required for the SCSS modules
            find: /^~(.*)$/,
            replacement: '$1',
        },
    ],
},
```

in the `defineConfig` file
So it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I solved it.
I just corrected the import in all dependent files:

@import 'variables' --->>>> corrected for --->>>>  @import './variables'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to cd into the root of your project folder. Two scenarios:

1. If you're deep inside the project, you need to run `cd ..` in the command line until you are in the root.
2. If you're outside of the project, you need to run `cd [insert root folder here]` and run your build again.