# Sass throwing "Error: Can't find stylesheet to import"

Tags: sass

Folder structure:

[image: Folder structure]

Error description:

[image: Error]

Sass version:

[image]

ParcelJS solved my problem by being able to compile my Sass/Scss code into plain CSS but i don't want to use it in such a small project like this one.

OS: MX Linux.

Sass is able to compile my code just fine if i don't use `@use` or `@import`.

Comment: From what I have seen `sass --watch` is generally unreliable when used as the docs say. There are a host of potential solutions in the canonical Q&A.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sass "Error: Can't find stylesheet to import."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127038/sass-error-cant-find-stylesheet-to-import)

Comment: None of these solutions worked unfortunately. I even tried using the Live Sass Compiler made by Glenn Marks which is supposed to be an up to date version of the old extension but it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try importing like below with a relative path:

```scss
@use ./abstracts/resets
```

Here is an [overview](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) of how Sass imports files:

> ### Finding the File
>
> It wouldn’t be any fun to write out absolute URLs for every stylesheet you import, so Sass’s algorithm for finding a file to import makes it a little easier. For starters, you don’t have to explicitly write out the extension of the file you want to import; @import "variables" will automatically load variables.scss, variables.sass, or variables.css.

> #### ⚠️ Heads up
>
> To ensure that stylesheets work on every operating system, Sass imports files by URL, not by file path. This means you need to use forward slashes, not backslashes, even when you’re on Windows.

> #### Load Paths
>
> All Sass implementations allow users to provide load paths: paths on the filesystem that Sass will look in when resolving imports. For example, if you pass node_modules/susy/sass as a load path, you can use @import "susy" to load node_modules/susy/sass/susy.scss.

> Imports will always be resolved relative to the current file first, though. Load paths will only be used if no relative file exists that matches the import. This ensures that you can’t accidentally mess up your relative imports when you add a new library.

> #### Fun fact:
>
> Unlike some other languages, Sass doesn’t require that you use ./ for relative imports. Relative imports are always available.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But it's really strange it did instead of the way i've done it, since it's more specific than following a relative path like in your solution, but i guess that's just 
one of the ''things" that happen in programming.

Comment: Glad I could help @Nihilo. It is related more to how Sass works. You could read more [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) on the official documentation, and I added an overview in my response.