# Getting error while trying add material-ui to the jhipster project

Tags: angular, material-ui, jhipster

I created a jhipster application with angular as front end ui framework. The jhipster and node versions are given below.

```
jhipster: 7.9.3,
npm: '9.6.5',
node: '18.16.0',
```

now i want to add matrerial-ui for creating a responsive application. For that i ran the following command.

ng add @angular/material

but then i am getting the following error log.

```
i Using package manager: npm
√ Found compatible package version: @angular/material@7.0.0.
√ Package information loaded.

The package @angular/material@7.0.0 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angulartest@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@14.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"14.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@">=7.0.0" from @angular/material@7.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!     @angular/material@"7.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"16.1.2" from @angular/animations@16.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   peer @angular/animations@">=7.0.0" from @angular/material@7.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!     @angular/material@"7.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\sanal\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-28T09_04_45_754Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\sanal\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-28T09_04_45_754Z-debug-0.log
× Packages installation failed, see above.
```

i tried unning "ng add @angular/material --legacy-peer-deps" also. but it is also not working.

I tried upgrading angular cli and core. bot of those times I got the following error.

```
>ng update @angular/core
The installed Angular CLI version is outdated.
Installing a temporary Angular CLI versioned 16.1.1 to perform the update.
√ Packages successfully installed.
Using package manager: npm
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 59 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
Updating multiple major versions of '@angular/core' at once is not supported. Please migrate each major version individually.
Run 'ng update @angular/core@15' in your workspace directory to update to latest '15.x' version of '@angular/core'.

For more information about the update process, see https://update.angular.io/?v=14.0-15.0
```

**What is the correct way to upgrade angular and install material-ui in jhipster project?**

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install the material UI after upgrading each dependency manually one by one. I used the following commands,

```
ng update @angular/cli@15 --force
ng update @angular/cli@16 --force
ng update @angular-builders/custom-webpack
ng update @angular-builders/jest
ng update @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
ng update @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
ng update jest-preset-angular
ng update ngx-infinite-scroll
ng update ngx-webstorage
ng update ts-jest
```

(Note: you will be asked to commit the changes after each upgrade.)

If there is a simpler approach than this, please share.

After upgrading the angular, I got an issue with importing scss style sheet. I changed the path and used the relative path for the style sheets.

this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127038/sass-error-cant-find-stylesheet-to-import) explains the problem and has answers for it.